# Ansible gets variable only from second execution

Tags: variables, copy, ansible

I've got a strange behavior of Ansible "copy" module when it is working with variables.
So, I have:
1. Config.yml:

```
    - hosts: temp
   vars_prompt:
   - name: server_name
     prompt: "Enter server number: 1, 2, 3..."
     private: no
     default: 5

   - name: server_role
     prompt: "Enter server role: app, admin"
     private: no
     default: admin

   - name: server_type
     prompt: "Enter server type: stage, prod"
     private: no
     default: stage

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Types and roles
      set_fact:
        servername: "{{ server_name }}"
        serverrole: "{{ server_role }}"
        servertype: "{{ server_type }}"

  vars_files:
   - "vars/variables"

  roles:
   - configs
```

2. "Configs" role with main.yml:

   ```
   ---
   - set_fact: folder=server
     when: serverrole == "app"

   - set_fact: folder=admin-server
     when: serverrole == "admin"

   - set_fact: stageorprod=stage01
     when: servertype == "stage"

   - set_fact: stageorprod=prod
     when: servertype == "prod"

   - set_fact: fast={{ stageorprod }}/{{ folder }}/{{ servername }}

   - name: Base copying admin-server
     copy: src=admin-server/config dest=/home/tomcat/config/{{ fast }}/
     when: serverrole == "admin"
   ```
3. Config files in ansible/roles/configs/files/admin-server/config.
   When I run playbook with default values of variables (5, admin, stage), I've got:

   ```
   TASK: [configs | set_fact fast={{stageorprod}}/{{folder}}/{{servername}}] ***** 
   ok: [testcen04] => {"ansible_facts": {"fast": "stage01/admin-server/5"}, "item": ""}


   TASK: [configs | Base copying admin-server]         *********************************** 
   failed: [testcen04] => {"failed": true, "item": "", "md5sum": "cb2547d6235c078cfda365a5fb3c27c3", 
   "path": "/home/tomcat/config/stage01/admin-server/config", "state": "absent"}
   msg: path /home/tomcat/config/stage01/admin-server/config does not exist
   ```

When I run this task one more time with same values, everything goes ok. But if I change some variable, it appears again.
I have noticed, that other modules, like "Template", works fine in same playbook with this variables. Maybe something wrong with "copy"?
As you can see, variable "fast" gets right values, but somehow, value of "servername" disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite ambiguous to how you are executing your playbook and what you are trying to accomplish with the prompted variables. If you are trying to spin up servers, it's likely better to declare them in the inventory without prompting. If you are trying to access specific ones, you should likely be using groups to limit their range.

If you are using ansible to generate a set of hosts for you. You will likely want to store this information somewhere consistently, probably in a instance tags, a key-value store such as redis, database, or in files, **before** you spin up the hosts and bootstrap them. Then run a second playbook to include the role.

If you are not in a public cloud, and for some reason cannot tag instances or group them inventory, you can also try using [facts.d](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d) to set the facts on the server and have them persist across runs, not just plays. Note that once you write to facts.d files, you should re-run `setup` module to gather facts again. Even though i use public cloud, I often make use of facts.d still.